# Enterprise Application Project in Java

Tags: java, jboss, ear, mysql-connector

I am trying to create a Enterprise Application Project in java.
I have learned some basics from http://pl.cs.jhu.edu/oose/resources/j2ee-tutorial/index.php link.

Project Structure is as follows:
*EAR  ( Enterprise Application Project )
*ApplicationClient  ( Application Client Module )
*Connector  ( Connector Module )
*EJB  ( EJB Module )
*EJBClient  ( EJB Client Module )
*JavaUtility  ( Utility Project, created first seperately and added to testEAR )
*DynamicWebApplication ( Dynamic Web Module )

I am using JBOSS as the Application Server.

connector module run as Java Application it works fine.
connector module run as does not provide run on server option.

JBOSS is not able to INSTALL the connector module. 
when I try to run EAR on JBOSS I get error log. pasted at the end.

interesting thing is i removed the connector module and added a java project, it's working fine.

If I create a Dynamic Web Project only and put all codes of Web, Java, DB Connection in separate packages, will I loose any feature that Enterprise Application Project can provide? Please explain this point beautifully because as I understand, we can put almost everything in Dynamic Web Project. Can you refer any EAR project in SourceForge or GitHub that I can download and reverse engineer and learn piece by piece from there. Any tutorial link explaining ejb, ejb client, application client projects is welcome.

### The error log on jboss when running ear project:-

```
15:56:20,119 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
15:56:20,291 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
15:56:20,322 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" starting
15:56:21,180 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
15:56:21,180 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
15:56:21,180 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
15:56:21,196 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.2.GA
15:56:21,228 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
15:56:21,228 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
15:56:21,259 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
15:56:21,275 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
15:56:21,290 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
15:56:21,290 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
15:56:21,290 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.6.final
15:56:21,306 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
15:56:21,322 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
15:56:21,384 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
15:56:21,384 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.7.Final)
15:56:21,571 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
15:56:21,571 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.1.GA
15:56:21,727 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
15:56:21,977 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Program Files\jboss\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments
15:56:21,977 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
15:56:21,977 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:9999
15:56:22,024 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found EAR.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called EAR.ear.dodeploy
15:56:22,117 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
15:56:22,148 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "EAR.ear"
15:56:22,336 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Connector.rar"
15:56:22,351 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "DynamicWebApplication.war"
15:56:22,351 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "EJB.jar"
15:56:22,539 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."EAR.ear"."Connector.rar".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."EAR.ear"."Connector.rar".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "Connector.rar" of deployment "EAR.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: org.jboss.jca.common.api.validator.ValidateException: IJ010075: The resource adapter metadata must contain either an outbound or inbound configuration
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.ParsedRaDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ParsedRaDeploymentProcessor.java:220)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.common.api.validator.ValidateException: IJ010075: The resource adapter metadata must contain either an outbound or inbound configuration
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ra.common.ResourceAdapter1516Impl.validate(ResourceAdapter1516Impl.java:333)
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ra.common.ConnectorAbstractmpl.validate(ConnectorAbstractmpl.java:305)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.ParsedRaDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ParsedRaDeploymentProcessor.java:136)
    ... 6 more

15:56:22,680 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /DynamicWebApplication
15:56:22,914 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "EAR.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"EAR.ear\".\"Connector.rar\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"EAR.ear\".\"Connector.rar\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment \"Connector.rar\" of deployment \"EAR.ear\""}}
15:56:22,929 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Connector.rar in 26ms
15:56:22,929 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment DynamicWebApplication.war in 27ms
15:56:22,929 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment EJB.jar in 27ms
15:56:22,945 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment EAR.ear in 38ms
15:56:22,945 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."EAR.ear"."Connector.rar".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."EAR.ear"."Connector.rar".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "Connector.rar" of deployment "EAR.ear"

15:56:22,945 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"EAR.ear\".\"Connector.rar\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"EAR.ear\".\"Connector.rar\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment \"Connector.rar\" of deployment \"EAR.ear\""}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your project properties and go to Targeted Runtimes, make sure you have JBoss configured there.

Let me know how it goes, I will try to help you out.

Comment: Deployment Assembly, Java Build Path and Project References all three are configured the way I have learned. As for Targeted Runtimes, all the projects have JBoss 7.1 Runtime configured. I also changed runtime of connector the jre7 and the error exists and same.